# october cms could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5, octobercms

First off I just want to preface that I am on shared hosting on justhost.com so I am not excluding them as a possible culprit and minimal proper PDO support. I just know that the site worked for a while before the error, and very little changed.

I am using October CMS.

I was logged into my backend from one computer, then logged in with the same account on a another computer and i got this error

> **could not find driver**

### (sitename).com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php line 47

> public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options) {
>
> $username = array_get($config, 'username');
>
> $password = array_get($config, 'password');
>
> **return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);**
>      }

I have not changed anything except what exists in the themes folder of the site.

I have checked my database config file, and all of that information has remained the same. Is there a direction I should look to solve this?

Comment: So does it still work when accessed from the first computer, but it doesn't when accessed from the second one? And if now it does not work when accessed from any computer, you should definitely check with the hosting, because I've see providers wreck server configurations when running careless updates on their systems (it's rare but not impossible).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bogdan. Yah it does not work in either browser now.

Comment: First, check if your database configuration is correct, if it is correct, check if the `php5-mysql` is installed and that the pdo_mysql extension is loaded

Comment: See this http://octobercms.com/plugin/october-drivers

Comment: Ok after trying out all of your advice I have discovered that of course it was my crappy hosting. There shared PDO support is having some bugs i guess. Your solutions I will apply going forward especially with the October drivers. Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after trying out all of your advice I have discovered that of course it was my crappy hosting. There shared PDO support is having some bugs I guess. Your solution for installing the October Driver plugins actually fixed some other issues I was having.